# Overriding decorated subclass methods

Tags: python, validation, subclass, wrapper, decorator

I'm fiddling around with inheritance and found a behavior that seems strange to me---namely, that some times I can override a parent decorator function (used for validation), but sometimes I cannot, and I cannot understand why or what the difference is.

A quick walkthrough in words---I have a person object I'd like subclass to a more particular person object.  The more particular one will have an additional field, "Dance," and will have different validation rules on a previous field, "name."

Here's my base case which works:

```
# Define the validation wrapper
def ensure(name, validate, doc=None):
    def decorator(Class):
        privateName = "__" + name
        def getter(self):
            return getattr(self, privateName)
        def setter(self, value):
            validate(name, value)
            setattr(self, privateName, value)
        setattr(Class, name, property(getter, setter, doc=doc))
        return Class
    return decorator

# Define the not string validation
def is_not_str(name, value):
    if isinstance(value, str):
        raise ValueError("{} cannot be a string.".format(name))

# Chosen to be exact opposite of above---demonstrating it's possible to reverse.    
def is_str(name, value):
    if not isinstance(value, str):
        raise ValueError("{} must be a string.".format(name))

@ensure("name", is_str)
@ensure("url", is_str)
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self,s):
        self.name = s.get('name',{})
        self.url = s.get('url','')

    def __str__(self):
        return "Person({{'name':'{}','url':'{}'}})".format(self.name, self.url)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

@ensure("name", is_not_str)   # require a number rather than a Name() object.
class Crazyperson(Person):
    def __init__(self,s):
        super(Crazyperson,self).__init__(s)   # idiom to inherit init
        self.dance = s.get('dance')           # add new param.

bill = Person({"name":"bill",
                "url":"http://www.example.com"})

fred = Crazyperson({"name":1,
                    "url":"http://www.example.com",
                    "dance":"Flamenco"})
```

This works fine.  So, the first object, bill, is created in such a way that the validation `is_str` succeeds.  If you try to put a number there, it fails.  The second object, likewise, accepts non-strings, so fred is created successfully.

Now, here's the case where it breaks, which I'd like to understand...

```
def is_Name(name, value):
    if not isinstance(value, dict) and not isinstance(value,Name):
        raise ValueError("{} must be a valid Name object".format(name))

# new object that will be a non-string type of name.
@ensure("firstname", is_str)
@ensure("lastname", is_str)
class Name(object):
    def __init__(self,s):
        self.firstname = s.get('firstname','')
        self.lastname = s.get('lastname')

    def __str__(self):
        return "Name({{'firstname':'{}','lastname':'{}' }})".format(self.firstname, self.lastname)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

@ensure("name", is_Name)   # require it as the default for the base class
@ensure("url", is_str)
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self,s):
        self.name = Name(s.get('name',{}))
        self.url = s.get('url','')

    def __str__(self):
        return "Person({{'name':'{}','url':'{}'}})".format(self.name, self.url)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)


@ensure("name", is_str)   # require a number rather than a Name() object.
class Crazyperson(Person):
    def __init__(self,s):
        super(Crazyperson,self).__init__(s)
        self.name = s.get('name','') # THIS IS THE KEY
        self.dance = s.get('dance') 

bill = Person({"name":{"firstname":"Bill", "lastname":"billbertson"},
                "url":"http://www.example.com"})

fred = Crazyperson({"name":"Fred",
                    "url":"http://www.example.com",
                    "dance":"Flamenco"})
```

In this instance, the Crazyperson fails.  The error suggests that the `is_Name` validation function in the `__init__` is still being applied:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __init__
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in __init__
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in __init__
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

It looks like it has called the `Name` initializer: `Name(s.get('name',{}))` on the string name "Fred".

But it seems it can't be, because in the previous example, I was able to remove a completely contradictory validation (`is_str` versus `is_not_str`).  Why is this **less opposite but failing more**?  In the first case it wasn't applying both `is_str` and `is_not_str`, why is it /now/ applying both `is_Name` and `is_str` with seemingly identical syntax?

My question is: what's different about the first way of doing this that causes it to succeed from the second way?  I've tried to isolate variables here, but don't understand why I can undo the wrapped validator inherited from the parent class in Scenario I but cannot do what seems similar in Scenario II.  It seems the only meaningful difference is that it's an object instead of a string.

(I understand that the better architectural way to do this would be to have a third more abstract parent class, with no validation rules that need changing---and both kinds of person would inherit from that.  But I also understand I am supposed to be able to change methods in subclasses, so I'd like to at least understand the difference between why one is succeeding and the other failing here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second setup, the `is_Name` function is *not* applied. You are creating `Name` object, regardless, in the `__init__` method:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self,s):
        self.name = Name(s.get('name',{}))
        self.url = s.get('url','')
```

Note the `self.name = Name(...)` line there.

In `Crazyperson.__init__()` you call the parent method:

```
def __init__(self,s):
    super(Crazyperson,self).__init__(s)
    self.dance = s.get('dance')
```

passing on `s` to `Person.__init__()` which creates a `Name()` object.

So when you create `fred` with `fred = Crazyperson({"name":"Fred", ...})` you are passing `name` set to the string `'Fred'` to `Name.__init__()`, which expected a dictionary instead:

```
class Name(object):
    def __init__(self,s):
        self.firstname = s.get('firstname','')
        self.lastname = s.get('lastname')
```

and this is where your code fails:

```
>>> 'Fred'.get('firstname', '')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Only set `name` on `Person` if no `self.name` has been set yet:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self,s):
        if not hasattr(self, 'name')
            self.name = Name(s.get('name', {}))
        self.url = s.get('url','')
```

and set `name` **first** in `Crazyperson`:

```
def __init__(self,s):
    self.name = s.get('name', 0)
    self.dance = s.get('dance') 
    super(Crazyperson,self).__init__(s)
```

Comment: I see, that makes sense---sorry, that was a different error I made, but plays into this all the same.  I've corrected it so that I have a new __init__ method for name.  However, it's obviously still calling the original method first and giving me the same error. How would I go about making the init in Scenario II initialize /this single variable for name/ differently in the second case? (without having to rewrite the 'url' part of the init common to both?)

Comment: Sorry, it is not obvious to me at all that the wrong method is being called in scenario II. What is the traceback? You may want to update your question with that information.

Comment: You can make the name *optional*. If no `name` key is present in `s` then don't set `self.name` at all. Then in `Crazyperson` set the name, remove the key from `s` and move on.

Comment: Sorry, just posted the update.  The new line added is in Crazyperson's init under `self.name = s.get('name','') # THIS IS THE KEY`.  However, when run, I still get: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __init__
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in __init__
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in __init__
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
`

Comment: Of course you do. You still call `Person.__init__()` **first**. The line `super(Crazyperson,self).__init__(s)` runs first, calles `Person.__init__(s)` which calls `self.name = Name(s.get('name', {}))` which finds the string, etc.

Comment: If I need name to be non-optional---maybe I'm still missing something basic, but how would I go about creating an init that requires an object for the base class, but requires a string for the derived class?  That is, how could I selectively override only parts of the init (name but not url) in the derived class?

Comment: Just saw your update.  Thanks, Martijn.  That's super helpful.  I feel like you've answered like 10 of my SO questions and I definitely appreciate your expertise and have learned a lot.